# Invalid use of matcher exception. Cannot evaluate mapper.toString()

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am new to UnitTesting and have been bashign my head against the wall with this exception I keep getting.

```
Item item = prepareItem();
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
itemList.add(item);

when(myMapper.selectEntryByParameters(
                anyString(),
                anyString(),
                anyString(),
                anyString(),
                anyString(),
                any())).thenReturn(itemList);
```

With a mocking class, that my test class extends with code as below:

```
public abstract class DataTest {
   protected Item prepareItem() {
      Item item = new Item();
      List<String> someIDs = new ArrayList<>();
      someIDs.add("0");
      item.setSomeIDs(someIDs);
      return item;
   }
   
   ...
   
}
```

When debuggin my code because of an error further down the line (probably unrelated, but I will include additional information below just to be sure), the debugger fails at this mock, throwing an InvalidUseOfMatchersException, stating "Cannot evaluate {someFileStructure}.myMapper$Mockito.mock$u83fh2.toString()".

Just to be sure, I'll also include the details of the error I am getting below. The method where the error is thrown looks like:

```
...
someMethod(List<String> newIDs, String id) {
 
   Item newItem = myMapper.getItemById(id);
   if(newItem.getSomeIDs == null) {
      newItem.setSomeIDs(new ArrayList<>());
   }
   newIDs.forEach(i -> newItem.getSomeIDs().add(i));

   ...

}
```

My mock, then, looks like this:

```
when(myMapper.getItemById(anyString)).thenReturn(item);
```

where item is the same item as on the top (the one being added to itemList).

It crashes on the line with getSomeIDs().add(i), throwing an UnsupportedOperationException. In the debugger, it shows that the item is perfectly fine and someIDs are of type ArrayList, however, once in the method (someMethod), for some reason, the someIDs field turns to ImmutableCollection. Maybe this will clear out at least one of the errors.

EDIT: Tried on mockito-4.5.1 and 5.2.0.

Comment: Mockito will not magically it an ImmutableCollection. Maybe something else (in your test or in your production code) is calling the setter and overwriting the value with an immutable collection?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, runnable example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to it being a part of a business logic, I can't really do that.